# Mistake with returning data structure that returns array of type char*

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I'm trying to return a data structure from a function named `urlTokener` where in the data structure one member is an array of type `char*` and the other is int.  When I print the values of the array in the function `urltokener` I get the correct type, but I see that in the main function where the returned data structure is used, the array doesn't contain the right values as the output is not right(not the same as in the function). It seems the function is not returning the data structure correctly. Could you please check and say what I'm doing wrong in the following code?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct tokenDetail
{
    char* theArray[256];

    int sizeOfArray;
};


tokenDetail urlTokener(const char *,char* );

void main()
{
    // String to be splitted.
    const char* url="/v1/AUTH_abb52a71-fc76-489b-b56b-732b66bf50b1/images?limit=1000&delimiter=/&format=xml"  ;

    tokenDetail newdetails;
    newdetails=urlTokener(url,"?");
    for (int i=0;i<newdetails.sizeOfArray;i++)
    {
        printf("This is in main where size is %d  and the value %s\n",newdetails.sizeOfArray,newdetails.theArray[i]);
    }
}

tokenDetail urlTokener(const char* urlLine,char* delimiter)
{
    char urlArray[256];
    strncpy(urlArray, urlLine, sizeof(urlArray));
    tokenDetail details;
    unsigned int index = 0;
    details.theArray[index] = strtok(urlArray, delimiter);

    while(details.theArray[index] != 0)
    {
        printf("This is in function %s\n",details.theArray[index]);
        ++index;
        details.theArray[index] = strtok(0, delimiter);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        printf("This is in function 2nd time %s\n",details.theArray[i]);
    }
    details.sizeOfArray=index;
    return details;
}
```

Please note : I'm doing it for c++, but I'm not allowed(by the person who gave me this task) to use namespace std, and library string. Which is why the code is similar to C. Because of this limitation I'm confused whether to tag it C or C++. So I tagged it in both c and c++. May be you could decide yourself.

Comment: Could it be that `urlArray` is a stack variable? The pointers in `details.theArray` are pointing to addresses in `urlArray`, which is not valid once you return from the function.

Comment: I haven't read very thoroughly, but the heavy use of `printf`, `strtok`, and similar imply this is c, so Luchian Grigore's answer about copy ctor and assignment operator is not relevant. Can you please clarify whether you want c or c++, and change the tags as appropriate.

Comment: I'm doing this testing for a bigger a project which has to be done in C++ but where I can't use namespace Std and string library. I can only use cstring or string.h and stdio.h. So, it's indeed c++, but I'm having to use alot of things similar to c. I hope that removes your confusion. @ Bobtfish

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately in the future. :)

Comment: `c++` is basically a superset of `c`, so that's not really a problem. `tokenDetail` is fine, the problem is in function `urlTokener()`, which has a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're filling the array with pointers returned from `strtok`, which in
turn are pointers into your `urlArray`, a local variable, which ceases
to exist once you return from the function.

Is this C or C++?  You've set both labels, and the solution is
different.  In C++, the obvious solution is to replace the `char*` in
`tokenDetail` with `std::string`.  In C, it's a bit more complicated.
You have dynamically allocate the strings in your struct (using the
non-standard but widely available `strdup`), and require the client to
free them.  The usual solution here is to return a pointer to a 
dynamically allocated `TokenDetail`, and a `freeTokenDetail` function
which the client is required to call on the returned pointer.  This
gives you total freedom in how you do your allocations and frees.  (The
usual solution is, in fact, to only provide a forward declaration of
`TokenDetail` to the clients, and to provide functions which they have
to call to access its elements.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not that `tokenDetail` needs any handwritten copy constructor, destructor or assignment operator, which it doesn't. The problem is that the local variable `urlArray` is destroyed when you leave `urlTokener()`, so the positions pointed to by the elements of `details.theArray` become invalid. And, of course, the same happens with the returned `tokenDetail`, which is a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement the copy constructor, destructor or assignment operator.

Because you return by value, the copy constructor is called on `return details;`, but the default one only does a shallow copy, so the field `char* theArray[256];` isn't copied properly.

Comment: If it's C++, the only correct answer is to use `std::string` (in which case, the default copy constructor, etc. would be fine).  If the code is in C, then copy constructors, etc. can't be used.

Comment: @JamesKanze it's C++, the op mentioned it in the comments and I edited the question. You're right, using std::string is the way to go. +1